# Avoiding Django DatabaseError relation "model" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

Upon initialization of an application in django, **before the postgresql database has been created,** if one tries to get/all/create an object they will usually see an error like this:

```
>>> Model.objects.all()
{StackTrace}
...
DatabaseError: relation "model" does not exist
...
```

In my application I would like to be able to test for the models existence and run code if it exists, is this possible using django?

Pseudocode:

```
if not (table_exists(model))
   return
my_models = Model.objects.all()
...
```

Comment: In what situation would you be running your application before creating the tables?

Comment: The problem I was trying to get around was actually because I had code in 'model/__init__.py' that ran a routine that required the models, creating a dependency loop. I didn't realize that Django runs each model listed in 'installed_apps', which was calling the __init__.py code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could catch the exception that's thrown while trying to access the model:

```
from django.db import DatabaseError

try:
    Model.objects.exists()
except DatabaseError:
    print 'DB not yet initialized'
else:
    print 'DB table exists'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but could you just issue raw sql to see if the table exists??

`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';`